# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in NextJS - getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have a problem with dynamic routing in next 13, I have dynamic page `[id].js` and trying to fetch the data

```
 const res = await fetch(`myAPI`);
 const resData  = await res.json();
    
 const paths = resData.data.map((r) => ({
      params: { id: r.id}
 }));

 return {
     paths,
     fallback: false
 }
```

It does not work and gives me error with `.map` function, if I hard code the path it works without any issue and give me correct output data

Hard coded example:

```
  paths: [
    {params: { id: '67'}}
  ],
```

I know that my map function should be correct as I tested in inside the component

```
  axios
  .get(`myAPI`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.map((res) => {return(res.id)}))
  })
```

console output in component return data without complaining, why I cannot achieve it in `getStaticPath`?

Comment: For starters, you should try logging `resData` to see what it really is.

Comment: how can I do console in getStaticPath? isn't it rendered on server side?

Comment: You should still see the logs in your terminal?

Comment: that's right, output of resData is correct as expected. Array of objects.

Comment: So it's an *array* of objects. Arrays don't have a `data` property now do they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resData` is already your array of objects, so you can "skip" `data`:

```
const res = await fetch(`myAPI`);
const resData  = await res.json();

const paths = resData.map((r) => ({
     params: { id: r.id}
}));
```

The reason why when using Axios you have to use `data`, is because Axios already gets the response data as JSON for you (as `data`). You were confusing Axios' `response` for `resData`.